# Condition that a homogeneous second degree equation in three variables representing a cone.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, quadratic-forms, orthogonal-matrices, quadrics

In my geometry course,we are told that a homogeneous equation of $2$nd degree in $x,y,z$ i.e. $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy=0$ will represent a cone with vertex at the origin iff the determinant $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    a & h & g \\
    h & b & f \\
    g & f & c \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$ is non zero.But if I take the homogeneous equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$,then the LHS is positive definite so $x=y=z=0$ is the only solution.So how can it represent a cone,even though the determinant $$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$ is non zero,the equation is not representing a cone.Please someone help me to clear my doubts about it.
Please see the following attachment for reference (from analytical geometry by Shanti Narayan)
[image]

Comment: OK deleted my comment.

Comment: This condition is over the complete quadratic and not over the homogeneous. (Null determinant).

Comment: @Cesareo please elaborate and write an answer.

Comment: @Cesareo I have quoted exactly from the book.

Comment: @Cesareo I have added a reference,please see.

Comment: See this same book at page 115 paragraph 7-2.

Comment: @Cesareo I saw it but what are you trying to show,I am just saying about a homogeneous equation not an equation of second degree general.

Comment: If the quadratic according to the book nomenclature is homogeneous then in the coefficient's determinant we should have $u=v=w=d=0$ and the condition is still $\det = 0$

Comment: @Cesareo But I can show you reference that the $3\times3$ determinant non zero is given as condition for a homogeneous equation to be a cone.

Comment: @Cesareo Please provide me with a proper necessary and sufficient condition so that a homogeneous eqn represents a cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assertion is false because taking $a=1,b=1,c=1,h=0,f=0$ we have

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & g \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 g & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with $\det M = 1-g^2$ and we have a cone representation only for $|g| > 1$

Comment: Please provide a necessary and sufficient condition for the determinant to represent a cone.